# Generate Lint targets using cmake (Flexelint/Linux)

Tags: lint, pc-lint

I am working on a C/C++ product that only builds in the Linux environment. It is a massive code base and generating lint targets manually is going to be incredibly painful. I know that you can link Lint into cmake so cmake generates these targets for you while it builds the code. Cmake has a macro called add_pc_lint (https://cmake.org/Wiki/PC-Lint) which does this for you. I wanted to know if there is something similar that could be used for Flexelint?

I currently have a PC-Lint license and wanted to ask this question before spending $998 on a Flexelint license. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

FlexeLint and PC-lint share the same manual so I'm pretty sure they are fully compatible on the command line. You should be able to use the same make files for both, or with minor changes. Otherwise they do offer a 30-day money-back guarantee.

Another option might be to run PC-lint under Wine. I tried this once and I got it working, but then I never used it much so I'm not sure how well it worked.

Answer (score -1):

So I did get a FlexeLint license yesterday and now I am trying to integrate it into my CMakeLists. I am looking at the source code of cmake's *add_pc_lint* function and trying to modify it to work for FlexeLint. If anyone has played around with it before, please comment. The FlexeLint manual is not at all helpful.

Comment: Answers are for solutions to the questions.  This is a comment and you should add comments like this to the comments section.